# how to check if a target string is in the List<T> C#

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I was thinking about finding a solution for this problem, 
The question said; ask the user to enter the target ssn (of type string) then search the collection of members, in case the ssn is found returns its index, other return-1, this should be done by defining and using a Generic method which takes List and string target as parameters,

My problem is that I can't correctly implements this method, I use CompareTo method to compare between the target and the List elements but this compression seems not logical since the target is string and the List elements are objects, 
This is my code

```
        public static int Search<T>(List<T> a, string target) where T : IComparable
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < a.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (target.CompareTo(a[i].ToString()) == 0)
                index = i;
            return i;
        }                

        return -1;

    }
```

Hepl me please to figure out a solution for this method, 
Thank you :)

Comment: Unless you know what `T` is, there isn't much you can do.  The description mentions a "collection of members", so why not use a `List<Member>`, or constrain `T` to `Member` (or `IMember`?) in the method definition?

Comment: And your method will always return `1`.

Comment: @ArghyaC return 1 :) The initial index is wrong, too.

Comment: @ArghyaC Unless the list has 0 items :)

Comment: yes i know this problem that my method alwayse returns -1, can you help me fix that?

Comment: I down voted because you didn't state what the entry requirements were. Spefically what is equality.

Answer (score 1):

Since `T` is `IComparable` you could do:

```
a[i].CompareTo(target)
```

The compare method must be able to correctly deal with string inputs.

Frankly, I think the problem statement seems weird. This is not how it should be done.

You also could make the entire method generic:

```
public static int Search<T>(List<T> a, T target) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (target.CompareTo(a[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I've fixed the code, too...

Comment: thank you so much, but the problom tha I have to take the target ssn (which is string) from the user, how can i compare ?

Comment: @usr You need 2 generic arguments here. target should probably be some other type than T

Comment: Really, if this is a list of string you should not be using generics at all. I have only done that per your requirement. Just replace all T usages with string.

Comment: the question asked me to make it string target :(

Comment: no it is not a list of string! it is a list of objects

Comment: So how do you want to compare objects to strings? What type are those objects?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use FindIndex built-in method?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("some");
list.Add("test");
int index = list.FindIndex(t => t.Equals("test"));
```

FindIndex returns -1 when not found

Comment: To me it looks like this is a school assignment.

Comment: Okay it may be like that

Comment: tank you, but i have to do it by using generic method to search for a target ssn in the collection